# Encoding characters when exporting using php in csv format

Tags: php, csv, php-5.3, export-to-csv

I have a problem with my export.

So I tried to export data to .csv with the following code :

```
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        $sFileName = 'test.csv';
        header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $sFileName . '";');
        header("Content-Type:application/csv;charset=UTF-8");
        fwrite($output, "sep=;\n");
        fputcsv($output, array('Nom', 'Prenom'), ";");
        foreach ($aFilterGifts as $value) {
            fputcsv($output, $value, ";");
        }
        fpassthru($output);
        fclose($output);
        exit;
```

Where the `$aFilterGifts` is an array with data. But If I have in `Nom`, data like this `Fossé`, when I export I get `FossГ©`.

Is there a solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure your php document ist utf8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, it's necessairy to make `$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');` after all headers,so thhe code is like this :

```
    $sFileName = 'test.csv';
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $sFileName . '";');
    header("Content-Type:application/csv;charset=UTF-8");
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```